# Create sub-tab similar to DevTools from Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

## Question

Can a Chrome extension add a "sub-tab" to a Chrome tab like the one that is created with Chrome DevTools (Inspect)?

### Background

I currently am adding a `div` to the side of a window from my extension by taking an HTML file, `sidebar.html`, that contains the following code:

```
<style>
#comment_container {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #aabcff;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
</style>

<div id="comment_container">
    <div>
       <p>...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

After a series of functions, `sidebar.html` is stored in a javascript variable `sidebar`. I then call

```
$( "body" ).wrapInner( "<div id='outerDiv'></div>");
$( "#outerDiv" ).width("70%");
$( "body" ).append(sidebar);
```

This appends a sidebar to the side of the window. What I would like to do is, instead of appending `#comment_container` to the document, to create a "sub-tab" like Chrome's DevTools (Inspect).

Comment: Are you trying to [add a panel to devtools](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels)?

Comment: I may be. Researching that link now. Thanks.